# How to rotate an object using the mouse holding down left button with Rigidbody and physics?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script make it rotating but also making the object moving away and even if i stop rotating it the object keep moving far away.  the rotationSpeed in the inspector is set to 500. the object have box collider and rigidbody components attached.

i want it to rotate smoothly each time i hold down the mouse down and rotating the mouse moving the mouse but that the object will rotate on place without changing position.

i wondering also that if the object have a Rigidbody component then it must be rotate in FixedUpdate or I can also make it rotating in Update  and in Update it will be without the physics ?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateDice : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotateSpeed = 500.0f;
    public bool isRotating = true;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private Quaternion targetRotation;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        targetRotation = transform.rotation; // Initialize to current rotation
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Handle input in Update to be responsive
        if (isRotating && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            float xRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            float yRotation = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(xRotation, Vector3.up);
            Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(yRotation, Vector3.right);

            targetRotation *= xQuaternion * yQuaternion;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Perform rotation in FixedUpdate
        if (rb != null)
        {
            rb.MoveRotation(targetRotation);
        }
    }
}
```

the inspector settings.

[image: inspector settings of the object to rotate]

Answer (score 0):

this is working as expected.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateDice : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float torque = 50.0f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public bool isRotating = true;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if ((isRotating))
        {
            rb.AddTorque(Vector3.up * torque * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));
            rb.AddTorque(Vector3.right * torque * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
        }
    }
}
```